# Не получается настроить NAT в linux

Tags: ip, iptables, маршрутизация, порты, port

Есть два сервера с линукс. Первый выполняет роль роутера, он имеет два сетевых интерфейса, один из которых подключен к интернету, другой к локальной сети. Второй сервер подключен к локальной сети. Задача настроить роутер так, что бы второй сервер имел выход в интернет и был доступен из интернета.

На роутере применял такие правила:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth2 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

где eth1 - интерфейс, который подключен к нету, eth2 - к локальной сети.

```
# sysctl -p
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

По локальной сети оба сервера пингуются. Но выполнить ping google.com на втором сервере не получается.

Comment: Если `ping 8.8.8.8` отрабатывает, загляните в `/etc/resolv.conf`. (на втором)

Answer (score 1):

Может, это поможт?

Рассмотрим случай, когда доступ в Интернет для роутера уже настроен. Теперь необходимо сделать его шлюзом в Интернет для машин во внутренней сети. Предположим, что внутренняя сеть работает через eth0.

```
# ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Следующей командой компьютер с Linux превращается в маршрутизатор.

```
# cat 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ipforward
```

Теперь производим маскарадинг:

```
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Остатся создать локальный DNS-сервер:

```
# apt-get install bind # /etc/init.d/bind start
```

Настройка роутера

В сетевых настройках клиента необходимо указать следующие настройки:

static IP
от 192.168.0.2 до 192.168.0.254

netmask
255.255.255.0

DNS
192.168.0.1

Шлюз (gateway)
192.168.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте маршруты. Если первый сервер и так, по-идее, знает все что надо - то второму наверняка никто не объяснил, что пакеты в инет надо отправлять через первый.

И да, Wireshark - ваш лучший друг. Послушайте трафик на первом сервере - будет видно, на каком этапе теряется пакет.